# Updating An Inventory List

Tags: excel

I have an inventory of parts at a certain location. Once a year, this inventory must be verified physically. It is quite an extensive list, so the easiest way to do it is to just pull the part and check it's part number against the list. This is tedious and cumbersome. So what I have done is create a formula where I just enter the part number and it returns the name and quantity expected (from the list, column labeled "STOCK"). If the actual count is different than what the list says, I want to enter the new count in a separate cell and have the list update with the new quantity in a column labeled "ACTUAL". Obviously, this could work with a one-time entry, but the actual count is going to change as I enter different part numbers and quantities. What I would like is when I update the count for a specific part number, the list count (ACTUAL) updates and stays when I enter another part number and quantity. I hope this makes sense.

So, Sheet 1 has the original part list with part numbers, descriptions, and expected quantity (STOCK) for each item. Sheet 2 has four cells: A1 is where I enter the part number, B1 references A1 and returns the part name from Sheet 1 if the part number exists (otherwise it tells me NO PART FOUND), C1 returns the STOCK count from Sheet 1 that matches the part number and description, and D1 is where I enter the ACTUAL (updated) count.

Here is the formula in B1 that calls the name (part number entered in A1):

{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$E$1000,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B1:$B1000=Sheet2!$A$2,ROW(Sheet1!$E$1:$E$1000)),ROW(1:1)),5)),"NO PART FOUND",(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$E$1000,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B1:$B1000=Sheet2!$A$2,ROW(Sheet1!$E$1:$E$1000)),ROW(1:1)),5)))}

Here is the formula on C1 that returns the STOCK count:

{=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$E$1000,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B1:$B1000=Sheet2!$A$2,ROW(Sheet1!$E$1:$E$1000)),ROW(1:1)),3)),"",(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$E$1000,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B1:$B1000=Sheet2!$A$2,ROW(Sheet1!$E$1:$E$1000)),ROW(1:1)),3)))}

I know a simple VLookup would work, but some part numbers refer to more than one item due to different manufacturers using the same number.

Thanks for taking the time to read this and any help you can give.

r/Carl

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What I would like is when I update the count for a specific part number, the list count (ACTUAL) updates and stays when I enter another part number and quantity. This then becomes the new list and stock count for next year.